# Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding ---

Tags: apex, visualforce

Could not resolve the entity from  value binding '{!pizza_name}'.   can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

apex class

```
public class pizza_menu {
    public string pizza_name{get;set;}
    public integer price{get;set;}
    public void addmenu()
    {
        try

    {
        menu__c m=new menu__c();
        m.name=pizza_name;
        m.price__c=price;
        insert m;

    }

    catch (DmlException e) {
    System.debug('A DML exception has occurred: ' +e.getMessage());
}
    }
}
```

vf page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="pizza_menu">
    <apex:pageBlock title="add the pizza" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:form>
                Name of pizza= <apex:inputfield value="{!pizza_name}"/>
               Price= <apex:inputfield value="{!price}"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`<apex:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) component must be used with fields on an sObject. You do not have an sObject here, just a primitive instance variable on your controller, so you cannot use this component.

The [`<apex:inputText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm) component, and other such input components, can be used with controller instance variables.

Alternately, you can store a `Menu__c` instance, created in your constructor, within your controller class, and reference its field values directly via `<apex:inputField>`, as for example `{! menu.Name }`. Your controller would need to declare

```
public Menu__c menu { get; set; }
```

and initialize it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a class level variable to `<apex:inputField>`, as input field requires additional meta-data information like label name, data type etc which your class level variable does not have.

You can use `<apex:inputText>` instead and get those values in controller to build you Menu record. Or else, you can have a Menu instance created and then you can bind fields of Menu directly to `<apex:inputField>`